# After rebooting my computer, my hosted website is no longer accessible (IIS)

Tags: windows, iis, hosting

Every so often IIS breaks for my home hosted server on my Windows PC, and I have to delete and reinstall it to make it work again. No idea why, but I've accepted it as part of life. I believe this is part of the issue now though, as recently, it does this every time I reboot my computer. If I have to restart it, or the power goes out overnight, then IIS no longer functions, despite having worked perfectly nicely previously. Now, the most recent time, I left the site on last night, and woke up to it ignoring requests completely. It stopped logging requests at 11:59PM and nothing seemingly has connected again. I could fix this by reinstalling IIS, but I'd like to come to a proper solution now that I've reinstalled it multiple times in only a couple days and had to spend an hour waiting reconfiguring the site.

All the W3SVC-related services are enabled, the firewall has the rule to allow port 80 through working properly, my computer's local IP hasn't changed and the router's IP hasn't changed. I've run this server for a few months now without issue, aside from the aforementioned occasional breakdown's IIS has that force me to reinstall it. I've tried iisreset in the command prompt, I've recycled my app pool and recompiled the site. Every answer I've been able thus far hasn't fixed this core problem. The only solution I know is to reinstall IIS and hope it's merciful with how long it gives me before it dies again.

It would be extremely nice if I could resolve this so IIS would just work properly from now on, but I really have no idea what could be the source of this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check the Event Log for interesting messages from the time that the problem occurred. Does using `iisreset` help when this happens? What is your Windows version?

Comment: Nothing unusual in the event log, just the last request being shown successfully connecting, as I said. And I mentioned it in the post, but `iisreset` does nothing whatsoever as far as I can tell. Behavior is identical when that happens. I'm just using windows 10, 0.0.17134 Build 17134 to be specific